# Performance problems with 13.04 and virtualbox

Tags: virtualbox, performance, 13.04

I just installed Ubuntu 13.04 (daily, full updated) and installed Windows 8 in virtualbox.

When Windows 8 is running a have huge performance issues on Ubuntu. Last week I had the same setup with Ubuntu 12.04 (full updated) and I had no problem with the overall performance.

Where is the problem and how can I fix it?

**PC:**

> ubuntu 13.04 x64
>   4 GiB RAM
>   4x3,1 Ghz Intel Sandybridge
>   On-board Graphics

**VBOX:**

> Windows 8 x86
>   1 GiB RAM
>   1 CPU
>   Graphics memory 128MB
>   Guest-extension is installed
>   3D-Acceleration active

Comment: What exactly is the performance drop you experience?

Comment: When the VBox is running many programs like dash, thunderbird, firefox, system-settings become grey for few seconds when I try to use them.

Comment: This is only guessing (hence no answer): try to add a second CPU to your guest VM, also try to apply an execution cap to each of them like 80%. Is VT-x enabled in both host BIOS, and the guest VM?

Comment: VT-x was already enabled. I switched now to 2 CPUs and I have no performance issuse till now. I will watch the situation and report later on how its peformed

Comment: After a few day and updates it runs pretty good. When I start the Windows 8 machine ubuntu slows down but after the start up it runs well. I think I had the performance issues because I updated and installed many software in W8 and it had 1 CPU. Now the software is installed and up to date. W8 has 2 CPUs and is starting in 5sec so there is not much of a problem now.

Comment: yeah, updating is always the best solution to solve performance issues. Let me suggest you write your own answer to your question with steps you took to resolve this? It may help future visitors, and we have this question "answered".

Answer (score 3):

I believe there is a package called virtualbox-guest-utils. Install it with `sudo apt-get install virtualbox-guest-utils`. This should get the virtualbox drivers. NOTE: You need the latest virtualbox to support guests with recent linux kernels.

Answer (score 0):

I had to do a few things:

install guest additions

install dkms (dynamic kernel module support):

```
sudo apt-get install dkms
```

add the line:

```
vboxvideo
```

to `/etc/modules`.

I had already installed gcc prior, you may need that to install the guest additions.  I installed the guest additions by the virtualbox menu, under devices; I didn't use apt-get.